# Is there a way to access ActiveMQ Artemis System Logs (enabled by Broker plugin) from a .NET Client

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have enabled message delivery logs on our Artemis instances using broker plugins according to this page. To draw some analytics by mapping end to end message delivery and receipt timings between publisher -> artemis server -> subscriber, I'm trying to see if the contents of the message that are being logged to artemis log file (To be specific Message ID) can be accessed by the publishing and subscribing .NET applications we have. Below are logs from the artemis.log file for a message with MessageId indicating various events.

> 20:50:24,552 INFO 
>   [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.plugin.impl] AMQ841010:
>   routed message with ID: 2231685496, result: OK
>
> 20:50:24,552 INFO 
>   [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.plugin.impl] AMQ841009: sent
>   message with ID: 2231685496, session name:
>   9d9c035b-176e-11ea-ab75-020ff9805db8, session connectionID: 68a7ec34,
>   result: OK
>
> 20:50:24,553 INFO 
>   [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.plugin.impl] AMQ841012:
>   delivered message with message ID: 2231685496, to consumer on address:
>   News.Source.T, queue: f0586137-5ad3-4c77-b2c7-5b68daad672c, consumer
>   sessionID: fcbcd194-3295-11ea-a2c0-0a89c5c4c02a, consumerID: 0
>
> 20:50:24,554 INFO 
>   [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.plugin.impl] AMQ841014:
>   acknowledged message ID: 2231685496, messageRef sessionID:
>   fcbcd194-3295-11ea-a2c0-0a89c5c4c02a, with messageRef consumerID: 0,
>   messageRef QueueName: f0586137-5ad3-4c77-b2c7-5b68daad672c,  with
>   ackReason: NORMAL

We are using AMQPNetLite for this and haven't found anything that can help us tie these messages sent and received to the logs that are being written to the artemis.log file. I've been looking to understand if there is a way to get a hold of the MessageId from these logs on the publisher application. Any pointers on this topic are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Messaging clients can't get data from the broker's log files since that data is just in a text-based log and not actually in the message broker itself. However, you could use something like the [`NotificationActiveMQServerPlugin`](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/broker-plugins.html#using-the-notificationactivemqserverplugin) which, instead of logging this information, will actually send *messages* with this information to the [management notification address](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/management.html#notification-messages). Clients can create subscriptions on the management notification address and receive the messages and then take action based on that information. The notification messages *may* not contain all the information you need, but you can easily extend this class to create your own plugin which includes all the information you need.

Comment: Is there a way we can log some or all contents of the message that a publisher sends to artemis?

Comment: Yes. You can implement your own plugin like the `LoggingActiveMQServerPlugin` you have been using and log whatever information you need.

Comment: I was referring to something that might be available out of the box, Our is a primarily a .NET team and we are using Artemis to replace another known Messaging service.

Comment: In that case, no. The broker will not log the contents of the message and even if it did it wouldn't necessarily know how to decode the contents of the message for logging anyway. As far as the broker is concerned the message is just an array of bytes. It could be text data encoded with UTF-8 or any number of other encodings or it could be binary data of some kind. There's nothing particularly complicated about implementing a broker plugin. Any developer with a basic understanding of Java should be able to do it.

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as such to help others who may have this same question in the future. Otherwise, please clarify what is still lacking. Thanks!